# What is difference between b3dm and gltf?

Tags: cesium, ol-cesium

What is difference between b3dm and gltf ?

When to use b3dm and when to prefer gltf over b3dm ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Update, 2021-11-10*: b3dm is being retired. 3D Tiles is upgrading to a new version dubbed "3D Tiles Next," and the b3dm wrapper is being replaced with raw glTF 2.0 (GLB) files plus an extension, [according to the blog](https://cesium.com/blog/2021/11/10/introducing-3d-tiles-next/#direct-gltf-references-from-3d-tiles).

b3dm ("Batched 3D Model") is part of the [3D Tiles](https://github.com/CesiumGS/3d-tiles) specification, and indeed b3dm [uses glTF as its payload](https://github.com/CesiumGS/3d-tiles/tree/master/specification/TileFormats/Batched3DModel#binary-gltf) to deliver 3d geometry.

A single glTF file delivers a (relatively) small amount of localized 3D geometry, along with materials, textures, and other metadata needed to render it on a client.  The 3D Tiles standard provides a mechanism to specify a hierarchy of geo-located glTFs at different resolutions.  For example, a vehicle may be easily portrayed in a single glTF file, but a whole city with all of its buildings and trees would need to be broken up into 3D Tiles, using multiple glTF files internally.

(Disclaimer: I work for the company that was originally responsible for b3dm and 3D Tiles, but I'm not on that particular team myself and I don't speak for them).